# ErrorHandler still showing error

Tags: vb6

When i type in text1 but it is wrong, the error is showing but the command2 is enabled. and when i enter the right name of my database. the error is still showing and the command2 is enabled again. i dont know what's happening.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

     conAddStudent.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID= 123 ;Initial Catalog=" & Text1.Text & "  ;Data Source=COM1\SQLEXPRESS;password= 123"

      On Error GoTo err
     command2.Enabled = True
err:
     MsgBox "none"

     Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your Exit Sub up before the error label so it exits before firing the error on a good run.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

  conAddStudent.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID= 123 ;Initial Catalog=" & Text1.Text & "  ;Data   Source=COM1\SQLEXPRESS;password= 123"

  If Text2.Text = "Valid Name" Then
      Text2.Enabled = True
  Else
      MsgBox "none"
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank your for reply sir.but when i type the wrong name the error is not showing also the text2 is  enabled is true

Comment: A "wrong name" is not an error, it is valid text that will not cause an error.  You need to add an If statement to check the name.  On Error will not accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: but sir can you help me how to check the name of my database i dont know if its possible

Comment: According to your connection string you are using SQL Express and opening it as a stand alone file.  So you need to know the name and location of your database and update the path on the end of the connection string you have.